# All children of this widget must have a key in Reorderable Listview

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i want to Reorder my list but i got this error.
 All children of this widget must have a key in Reorderable Listview

```
Widget list(list) {
    return Scrollbar(
      child: ReorderableListView(
          header: null,
          onReorder: _onReorder,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
          children: <Widget>[
            ListView.builder(
              itemCount: list.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (contex, index) {
                return _singleToDoWidget(list[index], index);
              },
            )
          ]),
    );
}
```

Comment: To begin with, why do you have a listview inside a listview?

Comment: @RémiRousselet  don't know exactly the idea about this reorderable list view i implement that way and i got this key error. i go through some examples but they are using static list and in my app my list data comes from an api call. don't know how to do this with that type of dynamic data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `key` is used to uniquely identify each item in the list since you will be moving them around.
You can do something like this:

```
ReoderableListView(
  header: null,
  onReorder: _onReorder,
  children: [
    for(var i; i < list.length; i++) {
      Container(
        key: ValueKey(list[index]),
        child: _singleToDoWidget(list[index], index),
    }
  ],
);
```

Or you can specify the `key` in your widget function itself.

```
Widget _singleToDoWidget(String title, int index) {
  return YourRootWidget(
    key: ValueKey(title),
    ...
  ),
}
```

*Just trying to illustrate your implementation and where the* `key` *will go*

Answer (score -1):

That's how i got solution to reorder my dynamic list.

```
void _onReorder(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
     setState(() {
       if (newIndex > oldIndex) {
         newIndex -= 1;
       }
       final dynamic x = list[oldIndex];
       list.removeAt(oldIndex);
       list.insert(newIndex, x);
     });
   }

final List child = map<Widget>(list, (index, i) {
     return _singleToDoWidget(list[index], index);
   });
   return Scrollbar(
     child: ReorderableListView(
         header: null, onReorder: _onReorder, children: child),
   );

Widget _singleToDoWidget(dynamic listItem, index) {
   return ListTile(
     key: ValueKey(index),
     title: Text(listItem.title),
   );
 }
```