# ReorderableListView does not identify keys in Custom Widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `ReorderableListView` which should populate custom widget, however even with keys passed in custom stateless widget class and constructor, I get the following error:

> All children of this widget must have a key.
>   'package:flutter/src/material/reorderable_list.dart': Failed
>   assertion: line 71 pos 10: 'children.every((Widget w) => w.key !=
>   null)'

Here is the dart code:

```
class CustomWidget extends StatelessWidget{

  String CustomWidgetString;
  String WidgetKey;

  CustomWidget({this.CustomWidgetString, this.WidgetKey});

  Widget _widget(){
    return Text(
      CustomWidgetString,
      key: Key(WidgetKey),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return _widget();
  }
}


class AppState extends State<App>{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Reorderable List"),
      ),
      body: ReorderableListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: <Widget>[
          CustomWidget(
            CustomWidgetString: "Custom Widget",
            WidgetKey: "value",
          )
        ],
        onReorder: (a, b){
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Using widget available in flutter, don't throw any error. Can you please help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `ValueKey` instead of just `Key`. Make sure the `ValueKey` holds the value. It's also critically important that you call `super` with the key so that it knows what the key is.

```
class CustomWidget extends StatelessWidget{

  final String customWidgetString;
  final Key key;

  const CustomWidget({this.key, this.customWidgetString}) : super(key: key);

  Widget _widget(){
    return Text(
      customWidgetString,
      key: key,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return _widget();
  }
}


class AppState extends State<App>{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Reorderable List"),
      ),
      body: ReorderableListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        children: <Widget>[
          CustomWidget(
            key: ValueKey("Custom Widget"),
            customWidgetString: "Custom Widget",
          )
        ],
        onReorder: (a, b){
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**More reading:**

https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d

[All children of this widget must have a key in Reorderable Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805166/all-children-of-this-widget-must-have-a-key-in-reorderable-listview)

**And watching:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc

Comment: Thank you so much! it works, I'll go through the links and see where I was at fault :)

Comment: Looks like super is what makes all the difference! + Valuekey! thanks again!